# Opening a MS .dot file through ASP.Net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

I have an application that when run in debug on my local machine has no problem opening this `.dot` file. But I've copied my application to a live server and when testing the app I get the following error message when trying to open the .dot file. This file is generated on a button click event and copies information from the system and pastes it into bookmarked sections on the template. The error is-

> "ERROR: Cannot generate call sheet - Word was unable to read this document. It may be corrupt. Try one or more of the following: * Open and Repair the file. * Open the file with the Text Recovery converter."

The server has MS Word 2007 installed. Has anyone ever experienced this before, or are there any known workarounds that will correct this for me?

Comment: Are you getting this error when opening the file on a client or while generating the .dot file on the server?